# From Kotlin how do I connect to an unsecure websocket?

Tags: android, kotlin, websocket

I have a websocket server running on Oracle Cloud. It has an `ws://1.2.3.4` numerical IP without ssl. I can connect and interact with it from console using `wscat`.

Now, I want to connect to it via Kotlin. I am using OKHTTP.

```
    client = OkHttpClient()
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url = socketUrl).build()
    webSocket = client!!.newWebSocket(request, webSocketListener)
    //this must me done else memory leak will be caused
    client!!.dispatcher.executorService.shutdown()
```

if url now has `ws://` only, this triggers the onfailure function. I have tried with other ws servers as well. If the url is like: `wss://this.isa.server` connection is established. However, using the same url, if i change `wss` to `ws` (i.e. : `ws://this.isa.server`) it does not work any more.

I think i need to turn off ws SSL verification. How do i acheive that in Kotlin?
Thank you

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie

Comment: unfortunately, this solution doesn't work. I continue to fall in socket failure

Comment: When you say "this solution does not work", what exactly did you try? What happened? Please be more specific.

Comment: I used: `tools:replace="android:usesCleartextTraffic"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in AndroidManifest.xml

The socketlistener, with a `ws://` server URL keeps on failing to connect. but the same server with `wss://` connects immediately

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74802428/769265 and implement `WebSocketListener` and override `onFailure()` to get more information about why.